# Edit cell properties of a handsontable grid

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a Handsontable grid where the user will enter some values to insert them in the database. When he submits the grid, I want specifics cells to be "readOnly". In this case, I want the first column to be "readOnly".

I use Ajax to send my data in my database. And in my callback function I want to edit the cells properties to "readOnly".

So what I have for now is :

```
var cellProperties={};
    var i;
    for (var i = 0; i < data_traitement.length; i++) {

        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
        return cellProperties;
    }
```

But the "cellProperties" option can only be used in the Handsontable definition. So I don't know what to use to do this.

Can someone help me please ?

**EDIT :**

With the advice of ZekeDroid, I tried to modify my cells definition :
So I've got this :

```
cells:function(row,col,prop){
    var cellProperties = {};

    if ([0].indexOf(row) !== -1 && col >= 0) 
    {
        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
    }

    if (readOnlyCells[[row,col]]) {
        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
    }

    return cellProperties;
    }
```

In my callback function, if I understood well, I have to change this `readOnlyCells` to `true`.

So I made this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data_traitement.length; i++) {
        readOnlyCells[[i,0]] = true; //I'm not sure of this line

    }
    hot.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your `columns` option set up, which you should, you can simply update the options using your HOT instance and the function `updateSettings()`. It would work like so:

```
hot.updateSettings({
    columns: newColumns
});
```

In your case, `newColumns` should be the new definition of your columns. I suggest making a function that returns this new object. This object would be defined as in the documentation page. On your ajax callback you'd make sure this new definition has the first column be `readOnly:true` and you're done!

If you wanted to do just cells, it could be easier than this. You can keep a map of cell coordinates like so:

```
var readOnlyCells = {};
```

Then on your callbacks, add the key value pair cell coordinates: `readOnlyCells[[row,col]] = true`. After this, you should just make sure your initial `cells` definition was as follows:

```
cells: function(row, col, prop) {
    var cellProperties = {};

    if (readOnlyCells[[row,col]]) {
        cellProperties.readOnly = true;
    }

    return cellProperties;
}
```

And that's it. You would want to update the settings like with the columns but there would be no need to change code.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the entire column to be "readOnly", I just want some cells :/ In fact, the user will insert 3 rows (for example), and I want the first column of these 3 rows to be readOnly. After, the user can add some rows and save again and again. I just don't want that the user can update a row he already entered. That's why I want to use cells properties to change the properties of specifics rows.

Comment: Ok, then use `cells` instead of `columns`

Comment: Could you help me please ? I tried your code, and I think it's a great idea, but it doesn't work, so maybe I'm doing wrong. So I edit my post to show you

Answer (score 1):

Can you try implementing a custom Renderer for this column? Then you can control the read only for every cell within that column.

Example:

```
function customReadOnlyRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {

    // your business logic to determine read only property of the cell
    cellProperties.readOnly = true or false;
    Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

After your ajax call, you update your data source and call render. The renderer will be invoked for every cell on this column with the latest data from the source.